# How Can I generate this exact Barcode

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I looked over the internet and on stackoverflow but didn't seem to find any help.

Here is the problem. I have barcode on a sticker when I download any barcode reader it recognize the barcode and give the number of the barcode.
But when I use a barcode generator and I give it the number to generate the barcode it gives me a different barcode, different from the original one.

Can anyone point me to how to generate the same barcode in the picture please.
Take a look at the picture to understand what I'm talking about.
I want a tool that I can give it the number in the picture and it generate the same barcode on the picture
[Image containing the barcode with its number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh963.jpg)

Comment: What are you using to generate the copies of the barcode?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry For The way I asked this question.I don't want an opinion about a tool I used every tool on the web but none of them helped.i'm looking for someone expert in barcodes to help me resolve the problem and generate the exact barcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you are trying to emulate is Interleaved 2 of 5.

Comment: You are very welcome. If you are familiar with plain vanilla Javascript, I have a small program on my github (MIT License) that I used to generate the barcodes on a webpage to help identify the symbology: http://brian-p-anderson.github.io/JS-Barcodes/

Answer (score 1):

Barcodes have different formats, called [symbologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode). 
You need to pick the right one, otherwise when you "give it a number" the start and end characters might well differ.